# Cut specific part of line and paste into specific part of another file

Tags: linux, sed, grep, copy, paste

#### Situation

I have a large file and I need to cut a part of a string (last three values) from specific line numbers. I have to paste the cut line fragment at the end of another line in another file. The lines in large files look somehow like that:

```
33 X2_C(4)     0.2454  1.1280  0.0073      1.4926102  15.5148009   0.0724955
34 X2_C(5)     0.2487  1.2156 -0.0585      1.5876791  16.7196951  -0.5831547
35 X2_C(6)     0.2529  1.2191 -0.1998      1.7741292  16.7675608  -1.9922789
```

For now I figured out that to get the last three numbers the regex should look like that:

```
\-{0,1}\d[0-9]{0,2}\.\d[0-9]{4,6}\s+\-{0,1}\d[0-9]{0,2}\.\d[0-9]{4,6}\s+\-{0,1}\d[0-9]{0,2}\.\d[0-9]{4,6}
```

The file to modify looks like that:

```
C(Fragment=1)
C(Fragment=2)
C(Fragment=2)
```

#### Expected output

```
C(Fragment=1)   1.4926102  15.5148009   0.0724955
C(Fragment=2)   1.5876791  16.7196951  -0.5831547
C(Fragment=2)   1.7741292  16.7675608  -1.9922789
```

#### Problem

1. I don't know how to tell grep to get a matching pattern from only one specific line.
2. I don't know how to append what was found into the end of a specific line in another file without deleting what was in the line.

Comment: Please do add expected output in your code in CODE TAGS and  let us know then.

Comment: I would suggest divide and conquer. E.g. `grep <large_file.txt "^\(33\|35\) " | awk '{ print $6,$7,$8 }' >>another_file.txt`, i.e. (a) filter out the lines by line number and (b) extract the columns.

Comment: @JamesBrown yes, it's just spaces. Their number doesn't matter too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one for awk, first the test files I used:

```
$ cat file1
111 112 113 114
121 122 123 124
131 132 133 134
141 142 143 144
151 152 153 154
$ cat file2
211
221
231
241
```

The awk:

```
$ cat program.awk
BEGIN {
    n=split(from,from2,",")
    m=split(to,to2,",")
    if(n!=m)
        exit
    for(i in from2) {
        from3[from2[i]]=i
        to3[to2[i]]=i
    }
}
NR==FNR {
    if(FNR in from3) 
        from2[from3[FNR]]=$(NF-2) OFS $(NF-1) OFS $NF
    next
}
(FNR in to3) {
    $0=$0 OFS from2[to3[FNR]]
}1
```

Using it:

```
$ awk -v from="2,3,4" -v to="1,4,3" -f progran.awk file1 file2
211 122 123 124
221
231 142 143 144
241 132 133 134
```

With the parameters `from` and `to` you can control from which records the last three fields are read from (ie. *from specific line numbers*) and to which records they are attached to - and in which order.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$(NF-2) OFS $(NF-1) OFS $NF; next} {print $0, a[FNR]}' file1 file2
C(Fragment=1) 1.4926102 15.5148009 0.0724955
C(Fragment=2) 1.5876791 16.7196951 -0.5831547
C(Fragment=2) 1.7741292 16.7675608 -1.9922789
```